# Store Downloaded Box File to Alternative Folder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, box-api

When using the `storeWithCallbacks:` method, files get stored in the apps `Documents/SavedFiles` folder.

Is there a way to set the destination to another folder path?

The following is how I'm making the call. The `localURL` of a **BoxFile** is readonly.

```
- (void) downloadFile: (BoxFile *) boxFile
{
    [Box registerObserverForDownloadQueue: (id)self];

     [boxFile storeWithCallbacks:^(id <BoxOperationCallbacks> on)
     {
         on.after(^(BoxCallbackResponse response)
                  {
                       [Box removeObserverForDownloadQueue: (id)self];
                      // Proprietory code here and a call to update the folder listing.
                  });
     }];
}
```

Comment: Can you share the box file downloading code???

Comment: Added the code that I could.

Comment: You might be able to fudge it using `-setValue:forKey:`

Comment: Played with it a little. BoxFile is not key value coding-compliant with the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is not a way to set the destination to another path.

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice to have that control.